# queryText with WHERE condition in aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Trying to execute the query on lambda in python using psycopg2.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('SELECT * from sample WHERE name='text1'','s3-bucket-name','file-path')".
```

Gives me an error - `syntax error at or near "text1"`.

Meanwhile, this query is running fine with name with type number but not working with the string type, and also this query is working fine without query_export_to_s3.
It seems to me like query_export_to_s3 can't work with string in `WHERE` condition.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your single quotes with single quotes.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3('SELECT * from sample WHERE name=''text1''','s3-bucket-name','file-path')"
```